# getting the profit and the types

Tags: c++

I'm a freshmen college and I need help, my prof. didn't explain well about the problem he gave to me.

Ron bought several acres of farm to grow and sell vegetables. Supposed that Ron wants to grow two types of vegetables.

do the ff.

1. Enter the total farm area in acres
2. The number of vegetables(1or2) that user wants to grow
3. If the user wants to grow two types of vegetables then specify the portion as a percentage of the farm land used for each type og vegetable.
4. Enter the seed cost, plantation cost, fertilization cost and labor cost for each acre.
   5.Enter vegetable sell its per acre.
5. Output the total revenue, profit/loss.

Comment: Begin by solving the problem using pencil and paper and some sample data. Repeat as needed. Once you understand how to do it, start writing code.

Comment: Thanks david for the advice I finally got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to know that StackOverflow is not there to code for you. Make sure you ask specific questions.

The best step to get into a problem is by taking it apart. Think of sample-values you could fit into the *variables* and how you have to work with them. Create a *flowchart* and then you can think of how to code it!

[Flowchart explanation with simple examples](https://www.edrawsoft.com/flowchart-examples-for-students.php)

Comment: Thanks C. Raffick I finally got the answer by trial and error, thanks for the advice im not really asking for answer but a guide, I mistakely construct the question. God bless

Comment: Trial and error is the best thing about coding, although it can be exhausting some times! Hope it was still fun!